# New list per user Entry

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am busy doing a school assignment and i have gotten stuck at this piece of code, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Please see the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

student_list = [['Tom','Information Systems'],['John','Computers'],['Johannes','Information Systems']]

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,**kw):    
        Frame.__init__(self,master=parent,**kw)
        self.searchValue = StringVar()
    self.searchBox = Entry(self,textvariable=self.searchValue)
    self.searchBox.pack()
    self.resultList = Listbox(self)
    self.resultList.pack()

    self.searchBox.bind('<Return>',self.update)

def update(self,e):
    print("*")
    self.resultList.delete(0,END)
    searchkey = self.searchValue.get()
    for student in student_list:
        if searchkey == student[0]:
            self.resultList.insert(END,str(student))
        elif searchkey == student[1]:
            self.resultList.insert(END,str(student))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Is it possible to create a new list per user entry or any alternate method?

Comment: you have wrong indentions - code doesn't work.

Comment: @furas Are you saying only the pure-hearted can run Python?

Comment: @furas Oh, indentions. I read "intentions". My bad.

Comment: @Rightleg funny mistake :)

Comment: I'll fix the indention's later, I just want to know if its possible to create a new list per user entry i.e make a list in a list in a list... for every entry the user makes?

Comment: yes, you can. Try it.

Comment: But how can you achieve this, NB, it has to be for an infinite amount of entries

Comment: Python `list` is infinite - only RAM in computer limits list size.

Comment: student_list.append(['New Student','A course']) would be a way to add an additional student and their course to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty but it works.

```
from tkinter import *

student_list = [['Tom','Information Systems'],['John','Computers']]


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=parent,**kw)
        self.searchValue = StringVar()

        self.searchBox = Entry(self,textvariable=self.searchValue)
        self.searchBox.pack()
        self.resultList = Listbox(self)
        self.resultList.pack()
        Label(self,text="Name:").pack()
        self.Name = Entry(self)
        self.Name.pack()
        Label(self,text="Course:").pack()
        self.Course = Entry(self)
        self.Course.pack()
        self.btnAdd = Button(self,text="Add",command=self.add_student)
        self.btnAdd.pack()

        self.searchBox.bind('<Return>',self.update)

    def add_student(self):
        global student_list
        print(student_list)
        name = self.Name.get()
        course = self.Course.get()
        student_list.append([name,course])
        print(student_list)

    def update(self,e):
        print("*")
        self.resultList.delete(0,END)
        searchkey = self.searchValue.get()
        for student in student_list:
            if searchkey == student[0]:
                self.resultList.insert(END,str(student))
            elif searchkey == student[1]:
                self.resultList.insert(END,str(student))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Now try to solve the next problem yourself... I've done both steps for you so far.